# TCPDF como redirecionar a pagina caso o código seja inválido?

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, redirecionamento-de-url

estou fazendo um relatório para impressão com o TCPDF porém estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades no redirecionamento caso o código seja invalido.
vejam o seguinte código:

```
if(isset($_GET['CODIGO']) AND $_GET['CODIGO'] != ''){

        $html   = '';
        $item   = 1;
        $dados = filter_var($_GET['CODIGO'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM TESTE_TABELA WHERE CODIGO = $dados";
        $query  = sqlsrv_query($conexion,$sql);

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
            $cod = 0;
            $manufacturero = $row['NOME'];
            $imagen = $row['IMG'];

            if($row['CODIGO']){

                $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
                $pdf->SetTitle('Imprimir Imagem'); //Titlo del pdf
                $pdf->setPrintHeader(false); //No se imprime cabecera
                $pdf->setPrintFooter(false); //No se imprime pie de pagina
                $pdf->SetMargins(20, 20, 20, false); //Se define margenes izquierdo, alto, derecho
                $pdf->Cell(200, 30, 'Relatório', 1, '', 'center', '', '', '', '');
                $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 20); //Se define un salto de pagina con un limite de pie de pagina   
                $pdf->addPage();

                //$barcode = '';
                //$barcode = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array($barcode, 'C128', '', '', 72, 25, 0.5, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>false, 'padding'=>2, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>7, 'stretchtext'=>6), 'N'));

                $html .= '
                        <h3 style="text-align:center; font-family:helvetica;">Nome: '.$manufacturero.'</h3><br><br>      
                        <img src="images/'.$imagen.'" width="520px"><br>';

                $item = $item+1;

                $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
                $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

                $pdf->lastPage();
                $pdf->output('Reporte.pdf', 'I');

            }else if(!$row['CODIGO']){
                echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>";
            }                
        }
    }else{
        echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>";
    }
```

O primeiro if esta funcionando de boa, se não existir o get, e se o código da url for igual a 0 ele redireciona. O grande problema é quando ele entra no while, ai ele entra no if faz a comparação mas caso o código não exista ele não redireciona.
Exemplo:
tenho um relatório com o código 7, caso eu digite na url 6 é um relatório que não exite, ele deveria entrar no primeiro if mas ser barrado no segundo, porém ele não faz nada, não redireciona, a pagina fica em branco, alguém tem alguma ideia do que seja? Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['CODIGO']) AND $_GET['CODIGO'] != ''){
        $dados = filter_var($_GET['CODIGO'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        $sql    = "SELECT CODIGO FROM TESTE_TABELA WHERE CODIGO = $dados";
        $query  = sqlsrv_query($conexion,$sql);

        if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query) > 0){

        }else{
             echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>";
        } 
}
```

Depois de muito tempo consegui, fiz essa condição se o if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query) > 0) for verdadeiro ou seja maior que 0 ele executa o código e abre o pdf, se for false menor ou igual 0 ele redireciona. Todo o restante do código que postei antes vai dentro do if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query) > 0